# How to hide a field in editable mode in grails application using .gsp file?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a situation in my application where I need to hide a field in one editable mode, but be visible and editable in another editable mode. For instance, I have ownerEdit where it renders a file _userid.gsp and all fields in the _userid.gsp are editable. At the same time, I am trying to render _userid.gsp file in userEdit mode where I need to hide some fields completely.

Any suggestions are welcome. Here are the sample codes:
I have ownerdataEdit.gsp which is call in ownerEdit.gsp. The _ownerDataEdit.gsp indeed call _userid.gsp as

```
<g:render template = "userid" model="${[userEditable:!ownerView.equals('show')]}"/>
```

Similarly, userDataEdit.gsp also call _userid.gsp as

```
 <g:render template = "userid" model="${[userEditable:userEdit]}"/>
```

And finally, the _userid.gsp has codes for the password field which I want to hide. And to do that I used if statement

```
<g:if test="${[userEdit:true]}"><dt input type="hidden"</dt></g:if>
<g:else>render the field </g:else>
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to be reading g:if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the mode in the render model:

```
render(template: "userid", model: [editable: true])
```

Then you have some options.

You could take the trivial route and use `style='display: none'` on fields when editable is true.  This has the added benefit of being able to easily toggle between editable and not client-side, if that has value to you.

You could use `<input type='hidden' ... />` fields if you need the values to come through to any submission.  Note that these can still be edited by a user who knows how to use the developer console, so you'll need to have protections in place on your server side as well to prevent malicious editing.

You could just not render the fields at all when you're not in editable mode, if you don't need them for anything.

Additional info:

Change your if conditions from:

```
<g:if test="${[userEdit:true]}"><dt input type="hidden"</dt></g:if>
```

to:

```
<g:if test="${userEditable}"><dt input type="hidden"</dt></g:if>
```

Comment: thanks. Maybe I missed your point. I am using _userid.gsp in two places. One in owner edit button and another in the user edit button. So, the user edit mode is only for those who shouldn't change anything in the field such as username and password. In fact, for user edit mode I want to hide the password field( I could make it noneditable while displaying, but I want to hide it).

Comment: Right, so pass in a variable (call it 'editable' or whatever you want) when rendering, indicating whether you want fields to be editable or not.  Then use that flag on your gsp (via g:if or ${editable}) to show things appropriately.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Either lost the field even in the show view or the field is displayed with the editable mode in userEdit.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code to get any more detailed help.  I would suggest showing at least the render line from your controller, and both gsps.

Comment: Added some sample codes if that clarifies my question.